# Plot the mean of the density curve with ggplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I need to plot a vertical line with the mean for each density curve.

I first tried this, but it plots the mean of the entire column, not the mean for each value of the factor cyl.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) 
+ geom_density(alpha = 0.3) 
+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(mpg),col=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

I managed to plot 3 separate means by calculating the means first with data.table.

```
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[,mpg_mean_by_cyl:=mean(mpg),by=cyl]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_density(alpha = 0.3)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mpg_mean_by_cyl,col=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

My question is: Is there a way to do it directly with ggplot? The density curves are well separated for each value of cyl, why is it not happening for the vertical line?

Comment: `mean(mpg)` is just a single number. If you want separate lines for each `cyl` value, the only way to do that with `ggplot2` is to supply a vector with the `cyl`-specific mean for each row of the `mtcars` dataset (which is what you did with data.table).

Comment: If you want a base R solution, you can do `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = sapply(cyl, function(x) subset(aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mean, data = mtcars), cyl == x , 2, drop = T)), col = factor(cyl)))`

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Ryan!